# Understanding `Namespaces`

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time understanding namespaces. It doesn't make any sense. However let me walk you through my experience of my learned knowledge.

Question: What's the point of namespaces if you have to `include` each file? How come I just can't say hey, this is the main root directory, I want to load all the classes in the `Core` folder. To my point of knowledge of my experience with c# I'll be able to use 'Call' a namespace/class as reference, or as a new class.

Since this was so a hassle, I've made a index.php file in each folder in which includes all the files within that folder. It's kindof like my own person class loader.

I just don't understand it at all.

Include namespace..

Include class "doesn't make sense "

use \namespace\to\class as Class;

```
$Class = new Class();
```

I just don't understand the usage of "use" if you have to require. That's how I've visually seen it done, I don't like the concept, and I'm hoping this isn't the concept, but I need explanations from someone please. I need to get a project done. Thanks.

- Sorry about this post being unformated. I'm currently using my phone, and don't know stackoverflow bbcode aswell.

Comment: Are you using `include`/`require` in your classed and adding `use` as well?

Comment: Normally you have an autoloader that requires all the files for you. So in a file in the project you just do `use Namespace\Class; $obj = new Class();`. To get a simple autoloader going just use composer, which you can also use to install/manage dependencies.

Comment: The use statement is also optional to use. `use Namespace\Class; $obj = new Class();` is just the same as `$obj = new Namespace\Class();` The obvious advantages of the use statements are that using the classes in the file will then require less code. It's also (imo) nice to have a list of the classes the file uses at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php):

> In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that authors of libraries and applications encounter when creating re-usable code elements such as classes or functions:
>
> 1. Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP classes/functions/constants or third-party classes/functions/constants.
> 2. Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate the first problem, improving readability of source code.
>
> PHP Namespaces provide a way in which to group related classes, interfaces, functions and constants.

See the linked manual page for more information and some examples.

[Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and namespaces complement each other and help avoid the includes you complain about.

Answer (score 1):

Because if files you include have identically named global variables/functions (not necessarily common, but very possible), they'll collide and the compiler won't know which one you want to refer to.

If everything is inside a namespace, unless the namespace names are the same, there won't be any naming collisions since then you need to refer to the namespace name and the function name.

This isn't an issue until you begin writing large programs that include other libraries, but it's certainly an issue that required the creation of namespaces.